# How to get soft limit of max open file handles

Tags: go

I have the following:

```
    var limit syscall.Rlimit
    if err := syscall.Getrlimit(syscall.RLIMIT_NOFILE, &limit); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Getrlimit:" + err.Error())
    }
    vlog.Infof("%v file descriptors out of a maximum of %v available\n", limit.Cur, limit.Max)
```

but `limit.Max` is the hard limit, not the soft limit. How do I go about getting the soft limit?

Comment: Is it `rLimit.Cur`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/45526674/13138080, I'm new to SO, so  apologies if that's not it

Comment: @Ollie, after `ulimit -n 4096`, both `limit.Cur` and `limit.Max` are returning `4096`.

Comment: @Ollie, you're right. Post an answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: Ah.  Slightly off, but glad it worked ;)

Comment: Modified a bit. The link you provided uses `rLimit` as the variable name. My example uses `limit` as the variable name. The important part is the `.Cur` which I had thought indicated the number of file descriptors currently open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`limit.Cur` is the soft limit. `limit.Max` is the hard limit.